# Como diminuir tamanho de array de bytes que representa uma imagem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um array de bytes na base64 que está numa String em C#. Ele representa uma imagem. O tamanho da String está variando entre 50 e 80 mil caracteres. Queria saber se tem como diminuir esse tamanho , comprimindo e tirando a qualidade da imagem.

Método HttpPost que recebe o array de bytes :

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]CreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PhotoFile))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foto não foi selecionada");
            throw new Exception("Foto não foi selecionada");
        }

        _professionalApp.CreateProfessional(model);
    }
```

Gostaria de ter um método que diminuisse o tamanho de PhotoFile - atributo String de CreateViewModel.

Comment: Tem algumas técnicas para fazer isto, mas ficaria muito amplo para responder. Dependendo do que deseja, não é necessário fazer isto. De qualquer forma precisaria de bem mais informações sobre a situação.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo acima.

Comment: Não ajudou muita coisa. A melhor coisa é não tratar como Base64 que desperdiça muito. É isto que quer?

Comment: Eu como eu poderia salvar a imagem ? O que quero é salvar sem gastar muito espaço, pois como disse a string de bytes tem entre 50 e 80 mil caracteres.

Comment: Eu adoraria dar uma resposta completa agora, mas estou tô exausto demais do trabalho pra isso agora, então vou só deixar um link aqui no qual a Microsoft documenta como compactar coisas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx se alguém quiser elaborar isso em uma resposta completa terá meu voto.

Comment: base 64 nesse caso só serve pra gastar mais espaço ainda.

Comment: Então como eu poderia guardar a imagem ?

Comment: Porque você não salva a imagem como binário mesmo ao invés de salvar como Base64 ? Utilizando  System.Drawing.* carregue a imagem, converta para JPEG e diminua ao máximo a qualidade dela, e então salve o arquivo binário (imagem.jpg), se isso não for suficiente para armazenar, utilize algum algoritmo de compressão  como: ZIP/RAR/GZIP

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho situações em que o avatar de um usuário é guardado no banco em **alta qualidade**, mas as vezes para renderizar um **thumbnail** bem pequeno (e como não tenho uma versão reduzida da imagem salva em nenhum lugar) eu devolvo essa mesma imagem, porém com um **tamanho reduzido** (para não gastar banda desnecessário do servidor e do client). Para isso, utilizo esse método de extensão (serve apenas para imagens):

```
public static byte[] ReduzTamanhoDaImagem(this byte[] imageData, int width, int height, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat type)
{
    if (imageData == null)
        return null;
    if (imageData.Length == 0)
        return imageData;
    using (MemoryStream myMemStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        Drawing.Image fullsizeImage = Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemStream);
        if (width <= 0 || width > fullsizeImage.Width)
            width = fullsizeImage.Width;
        if (height <= 0 || height > fullsizeImage.Height)
            height = fullsizeImage.Height;
        Drawing.Image newImage = fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        using (MemoryStream myResult = new MemoryStream())
        {
            newImage.Save(myResult, type);
            return myResult.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Então você poderia utilizar dessa forma:

```
model.PhotoFile = model.PhotoFile.ReduzTamanhoDaImagem(50, 30, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

...o que iria reduzir a resolução da imagem para **50x30** (nesse método em particular, se a imagem já tem a largura/altura menor do que o passado por parâmetro, ele manterá o tamanho original).

*Não sou expert em manipulação de imagens, mas entendo que o fato de reduzir a resolução não causa perda da qualidade da imagem, no entanto ao tentar redimensioná-la ao tamanho original (que seria maior), aí sim pode ocorrer a perda da qualidade.*